# how to get only int part from the list and store in array?

Tags: c#, linq

In lst i have studentId(int) and CosineSimilarity(double) i have sorted them in descending order now after that i want only integer values from lst in int array

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? Cosine { get; set; }
}

public List<Student> GetStuCosineSimilarity()
{ 
    List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();

    lst = (from s in DB.Students
           select new Student()
           {
               Id = s.StudentId,
               Cosine = s.cosineSimilarity
           }).ToList();

    lst = lst.OrderBy(k => k.Cosine).ToList(); // Sorting the float value
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: You already asked a question about `orderby`, now for `select`, are you going to ask for every LINQ operator.

Comment: `lst.Select(k=> k.Id).ToArray();`. You should in future do some research as answers to these simple questions already exist all over SO.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look something like the code below.  Made some changes to posted code to remove compiler errors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            List<Student> students = student.GetStuCosineSimilarity();
            int[] ids = students.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
        }
    }
    static public class DB
    {
        public static List<Student> Students { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double? Cosine { get; set; }

        public List<Student> GetStuCosineSimilarity()
        {
            List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();

            lst = (from s in DB.Students
                   select new Student()
                   {
                       Id = s.Id,
                       Cosine = s.Cosine
                   }).ToList();

            lst = lst.OrderBy(k => k.Cosine).ToList(); // Sorting the float value
            return lst;
        }
    }
}
```